# Parsing html tags when displaying text in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, html-parsing

I just want to parse html tags like those making text bolded  etc.

But no real webpages would be displayed in my control. 
Moreover no editing would be supported, just displaying.

For example for the text content:

```
abc <b>bold</b> def
```

I would like to display at my control like this:

abc **bold** def

What is the best way to parse such an input text and display it ?

Should I use for this WebBrowser control or RichText or TextBlock would sufficient too ?

Do I must to use HtmlDocument or HTMLDocument or FlowDocument or the other one ?

Please let me any suggestion.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

You might use a control such as `HtmlPanel` or `HtmlLabel` from the `HtmlRenderer.WPF` package.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlRenderer.WPF

From their [documentation](https://htmlrenderer.codeplex.com/documentation):

```
<wpf:HtmlPanel Text="&lt;p&gt;&lt;h1&gt;Hello&lt;/h1&gt; World&lt;/p&gt;"/>
```

With namespace import:

```
xmlns:wpf="clr-namespace:TheArtOfDev.HtmlRenderer.WPF;assembly=HtmlRenderer.WPF"
```

If you bind the HTML string, you don't need to escape it. It's only escaped here because it's within the XAML.

More information at:

https://htmlrenderer.codeplex.com/

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. I would like to prioritize on solutions not involving third party sources if possible. Anyway thank you for the answer. If I would not find any build in solution, then I would use this one. Thanks !

Comment: Unfortunately, with this library its impossible to set size, color etc of the text. Everything have to be done in html.

Comment: @NomadDeveloper you should be able to scale the entire control, even if via a layout or render transform, but the content of the HTML area is controlled by the HTML itself. If you need to modify details in the rendering of the HTML document, you may be able to inject your own CSS.